# Standard for "secure workstations" resisting screen grabs

Tags: standards, screen-capture

In his talk ["Keynote address: securing the individual" at authenticate2020](https://invidious.kavin.rocks/watch?v=N-Xi1VUo-ic) (around 23:44), Whit Diffie asks

> "ever wonder why an app can come on and grab your whole screen? There's a whole set of standards to resist that. They were called 'secure workstations' when the military got interested in it, but it isn't much available in ordinary operating systems."

Anyone know the standards he's referring to, and if they were ever applied?

Comment: You can grab any screen with a camera...

Comment: Compositing window managers can resist full screen grabs. For Linux at least, you can look into the difference between the Wayland security model and the X11 security model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anyone know the standards he's referring to, and if they were ever applied?

It's hard to say for sure. Maybe you could ask him.

There are a lot of potentially relevant old standards, but they are hard to find. For example: "DDS-2600-5502-97 Security Requirements for System High and Compartmented Mode Workstations" from 1987.

Here a [link](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/conference-paper/1996/10/22/proceedings-of-the-19th-nissc-1996/documents/paper041/tx-hdw.pdf) to a related paper that cites to that standard.